# How to I programatically search for a specific entityform submission?

Tags: database, entities

I want to search for submissions where a field has a specific value.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$formentities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'entityform')
  ->entityCondition('type', 'selection_form')
  ->fieldCondition('field_session', 'value', $session_id, '=' )
  ->range(0,1)
  ->execute();
```

Can't quite get the code correct.  Can you help?  I think this might be looking for the form, rather than submissions......